# How to change the font COLOR for Linux Mint XFCE desktop

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, colors, fonts, desktop

Using Linux Mint XFCE 20.2 and a while back I installed a KDE Plasma desktop to try it out. Ended up not liking it and just stuck with this one.

For some reason, while I was switching between KDE and XFCE, the text on my desktop icons changed to black with a black shadow and I don't know how to change it back (it used to be white with a black shadow). I've tried changing the theme and editing the gtk.css and colors.css files, logging out then back in, but nothing happened.

What do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Xfce 4.14 or better, put the following into `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`, creating `gtk.css` if necessary...

```
XfdesktopIconView.label {
        color: xxxxxx;
}
```

...where `xxxxxx` is a color name (e.g. `yellow`) or a color hex code (e.g. `#F6E417`). Then, log out and in again or reboot for the change to take effect.

Source: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1966139#p1966139

Comment: I have edited that file, it doesn't work, plus it imports colors from a file called *colors.css*

Comment: Assuming you've taken a look at `colors.css` to see if there's anything there that might be causing the problem and found nothing, I might try changing the color attribute in `gtk.css` to `color xxxxxx !important;`. It may allow that attribute to take precedence over whatever other css that's being applied.

Comment: Note that while the link I referred is to a page on Mint's forums, I tested in Xfce on Fedora and was able to just log out and in again for a change to take effect. I don't know, but rebooting may be necessary in Mint.